# Ifnum and missing } inserted inside tabular environment

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write a budget proposal and I'm using counters to control the number and price of each item. I also created a table and used \ifnum to control if the item should be included in the proposal (only if the quantity is more than 0).

I'm getting "Missing } inserted" inside the first \ifnum, but I can't seem to find why that is the case. Am I missing something obvious?

There is also the problem of, when the quantity of an item is 0, the line is still included when generating the table (just ignoring the first cell), despite being inside the \ifnum which should be false. This also prompts a "extra \fi" error on the second \ifnum.

Here is the following code and the table generated by it:

```latex
\section{Serviços executados em Outubro de 2018 com validade até Outubro de 2019}
\newcounter{p_4}
\newcounter{p_4Q}
\newcounter{p_6}
\newcounter{p_6Q}
\newcounter{ap_10}
\newcounter{ap_10Q}
\newcounter{co_4}
\newcounter{co_4Q}
\newcounter{co_6}
\newcounter{co_6Q}
\newcounter{mangueira}
\newcounter{mangueiraQ}
\setcounter{p_4}        {20} %pqsp 4kg
\setcounter{p_4Q}       {2} %quantidade psqp 4kg
\setcounter{p_6}        {45} %pqsp 6kg
\setcounter{p_6Q}       {0} %quantidade pqsp 6kg
\setcounter{ap_10}      {20} %ap 10 litros
\setcounter{ap_10Q}     {1} %quantidade ap 10 litros
\setcounter{co_4}       {18} %co2 4kg
\setcounter{co_4Q}      {4} %quantidade co2 4kg
\setcounter{co_6}       {28} %co2 6kg
\setcounter{co_6Q}      {3} %quantidade co2 6kg
\setcounter{mangueira}  {15} %reteste mangueira
\setcounter{mangueiraQ} {22} %quantidade reteste mangueira
\newcounter{itemCounter}
\setcounter{itemCounter}{1}

%\ifnum \value{p_4Q}>0
%{01  p_6SP 4Kg   \arabic{p_4Q}        R\$ \arabic{p_4},00         R\$ \the\numexpr\p_6Quatro*\p_6QuatroQ\relax,00 \\}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Item} & Especificação & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Quantidade} & Valor Unitário & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Valor Total} \\ \hline

\ifnum\value{p_4Q}>0
{
    \arabic{itemCounter} & PQSP 4Kg & \arabic{p_4Q} & R\$ \arabic{p_4},00 & R\$ \the\numexpr\value{p_4}*\value{p_4Q}\relax,00 \\ \hline
    \stepcounter{itemCounter}
}
\fi

\ifnum\value{p_6Q}>0
{
    \arabic{itemCounter} & PQSP 6Kg & \arabic{p_6Q} & R\$ \arabic{p_6},00 & R\$ \the\numexpr\value{p_6}*\value{p_6Q}\relax,00 \\ \hline
    \stepcounter{itemCounter}
}
\fi

\ifnum\value{ap_10Q}>0
{
    \arabic{itemCounter} & AP 10L & \arabic{ap_10Q} & R\$ \arabic{ap_10},00 & R\$ \the\numexpr\value{ap_10}*\value{ap_10Q}\relax,00 \\ \hline
    \stepcounter{itemCounter}
}
\fi

\ifnum\value{co_4Q}>0
{
    \arabic{itemCounter} & CO2 4Kg & \arabic{co_4Q} & R\$ \arabic{co_4},00 & R\$ \the\numexpr\value{co_4}*\value{co_4Q}\relax,00 \\ \hline
    \stepcounter{itemCounter}
}
\fi

\ifnum\value{co_6Q}>0
{
    \arabic{itemCounter} & CO2 6Kg & \arabic{co_6Q} & R\$ \arabic{co_6},00 & R\$ \the\numexpr\value{co_6}*\value{co_6Q}\relax,00 \\ \hline
    \stepcounter{itemCounter}
}
\fi

\ifnum\value{mangueiraQ}>0
{
    \arabic{itemCounter} & Reteste de mangueiras de incêndio tipo 1 & \arabic{mangueiraQ} & R\$ \arabic{mangueira},00 & R\$ \the\numexpr\value{mangueira}*\value{mangueiraQ}\relax,00 \\ \hline
    \stepcounter{itemCounter}
}
\fi

Total &  &  &  & R\$ 
\the\numexpr\value{p_4}*\value{p_4Q} +
\the\numexpr\value{p_6}*\value{p_6Q} + 
\the\numexpr\value{ap_10}*\value{ap_10Q} + 
\the\numexpr\value{co_4}*\value{co_4Q} +
\the\numexpr\value{co_6}*\value{co_6Q} +
\the\numexpr\value{mangueira}*\value{mangueiraQ}\relax,00 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Wrongly Generated Table]

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the little trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131284/36296 to hide the ampersands with `\uppercase{&}` from the table

in addition

- the group around each row needs to be removed
- empty lines removed
- moved `\stepcounter{itemCounter}` inside the row, otherwise it will start a new cell

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\section{Serviços executados em Outubro de 2018 com validade até Outubro de 2019}
\newcounter{p_4}
\newcounter{p_4Q}
\newcounter{p_6}
\newcounter{p_6Q}
\newcounter{ap_10}
\newcounter{ap_10Q}
\newcounter{co_4}
\newcounter{co_4Q}
\newcounter{co_6}
\newcounter{co_6Q}
\newcounter{mangueira}
\newcounter{mangueiraQ}
\setcounter{p_4}        {20} %pqsp 4kg
\setcounter{p_4Q}       {2} %quantidade psqp 4kg
\setcounter{p_6}        {45} %pqsp 6kg
\setcounter{p_6Q}       {0} %quantidade pqsp 6kg
\setcounter{ap_10}      {20} %ap 10 litros
\setcounter{ap_10Q}     {1} %quantidade ap 10 litros
\setcounter{co_4}       {18} %co2 4kg
\setcounter{co_4Q}      {4} %quantidade co2 4kg
\setcounter{co_6}       {28} %co2 6kg
\setcounter{co_6Q}      {3} %quantidade co2 6kg
\setcounter{mangueira}  {15} %reteste mangueira
\setcounter{mangueiraQ} {22} %quantidade reteste mangueira
\newcounter{itemCounter}
\setcounter{itemCounter}{1}

%\ifnum \value{p_4Q}>0
%{01  p_6SP 4Kg   \arabic{p_4Q}        R\$ \arabic{p_4},00         R\$ \the\numexpr\p_6Quatro*\p_6QuatroQ\relax,00 \\}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Item} & Especificação & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Quantidade} & Valor Unitário & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Valor Total} \\ \hline
\ifnum\value{p_4Q}>0
    \arabic{itemCounter} \uppercase{&} PQSP 4Kg \uppercase{&} \arabic{p_4Q} \uppercase{&} R\$ \arabic{p_4},00 \uppercase{&} R\$ \the\numexpr\value{p_4}*\value{p_4Q}\relax,00     \stepcounter{itemCounter}\\ \hline
\fi%
\ifnum\value{p_6Q}>0
    \arabic{itemCounter} \uppercase{&} PQSP 6Kg \uppercase{&} \arabic{p_6Q} \uppercase{&} R\$ \arabic{p_6},00 \uppercase{&} R\$ \the\numexpr\value{p_6}*\value{p_6Q}\relax,00     \stepcounter{itemCounter}\\ \hline
\fi%
\ifnum\value{ap_10Q}>0
    \arabic{itemCounter} \uppercase{&} AP 10L \uppercase{&} \arabic{ap_10Q} \uppercase{&} R\$ \arabic{ap_10},00 \uppercase{&} R\$ \the\numexpr\value{ap_10}*\value{ap_10Q}\relax,00     \stepcounter{itemCounter}\\ \hline
\fi%
\ifnum\value{co_4Q}>0
    \arabic{itemCounter} \uppercase{&} CO2 4Kg \uppercase{&} \arabic{co_4Q} \uppercase{&} R\$ \arabic{co_4},00 \uppercase{&} R\$ \the\numexpr\value{co_4}*\value{co_4Q}\relax,00\stepcounter{itemCounter} \\ \hline
\fi
\ifnum\value{co_6Q}>0
    \arabic{itemCounter} \uppercase{&} CO2 6Kg \uppercase{&} \arabic{co_6Q} \uppercase{&} R\$ \arabic{co_6},00 \uppercase{&} R\$ \the\numexpr\value{co_6}*\value{co_6Q}\relax,00 \stepcounter{itemCounter}\\ \hline
\fi
\ifnum\value{mangueiraQ}>0
    \arabic{itemCounter} \uppercase{&} Reteste de mangueiras de incêndio tipo 1 \uppercase{&} \arabic{mangueiraQ} \uppercase{&} R\$ \arabic{mangueira},00 \uppercase{&} R\$ \the\numexpr\value{mangueira}*\value{mangueiraQ}\relax,00 \stepcounter{itemCounter}\\ \hline
\fi
Total &  &  &  & R\$ 
\the\numexpr\value{p_4}*\value{p_4Q} +
\the\numexpr\value{p_6}*\value{p_6Q} + 
\the\numexpr\value{ap_10}*\value{ap_10Q} + 
\the\numexpr\value{co_4}*\value{co_4Q} +
\the\numexpr\value{co_6}*\value{co_6Q} +
\the\numexpr\value{mangueira}*\value{mangueiraQ}\relax,00 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]